# C++ String stream ignore() not working

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was solving a question on hackerrank and came across this problem involving string streams.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-stringstream/problem

For Extracting data, hackerrank has given an example:

```
stringstream ss("23,4,56");
char ch;
int a, b, c;
ss >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c;  // a = 23, b = 4, c = 56
```

However, when I try to export it to a vector, I have to escape the ',' using:

```
stringstream ss(str);
vector<int> vect;
int i;

while (ss >> i)
{
vect.push_back(i);

if (ss.peek() == ',')
    ss.ignore();
}
```

Why can't I use the extraction operation to get the required word here? Shouldn't the stream escape the ','(Sorry for the noob-level question)?

Comment: Do you understand what `>> ch` is doing in that first code snippet?

Comment: I clearly did not. I thought it was defaulting to ',' delimiting but Remy has opened my eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator>>` extracts the next delimited token, only so far as characters actually belong to the requested data type.  So, when using `operator>>` to read an `int`, it will extract only digits, not letters, punctuation, etc.  That means a comma following a number has to be read separately.

In the first example:

1. `ss >> a` reads the first `int` in the stream
2. then `>> ch` reads the comma after it
3. then `>> b` reads the next `int`
4. then `>> ch` reads the comma after it
5. then `>> c` reads the next `int`

In the second example:

1. `ss >> i` reads the next `int` in the stream, breaking the loop if fails or EOF
2. then `ss.peek()` checks if a comma exists (since the last `int` doesn't have one), and if found then `ss.ignore()` skips past it
3. goto #1

If you try to use `operator>>` to read a comma that doesn't exist, it will set the stream's `eofbit` state and fail the extraction.  If you use `while (ss >> i >> ch)`, the `while` would evaluate as `false` when the last `int` is reached. Even though `ss >> i` would succeed, `>> ch` would fail, and thus `i` would not be added to the `vector`.

In theory, you could replace `if (ss.peek() == ',') ss.ignore();` inside the loop with `char ch; ss >> ch` instead.  The end effect would be the same, at least for a string like `"23,4,56"`.  But, let's say you were given something like `"23 4 56"` instead.  The first example would fail to handle that correctly, but the second example would handle it just fine when using `peek()+ignore()`, but not when using `ss >> ch`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this code to escape the ','

```
std::string valstr;
while (std::getline(ss, valstr, ','))
{
    vect.push_back(std::stoi(valstr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! TIL.